# Using multiple ssh keys with Github, with one being default

Tags: ssh, git

I want to configure my SSH client to work with different keys when pushing to GitHub, with one key being the "default".

I thought that putting this into `.ssh/config` will give me what I need:

```
Host github-foo
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_FOO

Host *
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_BAR
```

according to `man ssh_config`, when git is connecting to a remote with url `git@github-foo:myuser/myproject`, ssh should take the first value of IdentityFile form matching `Host` blocks  (`~/.ssh/id_rsa_FOO` in this case) and use it.  However, ssh is authenticating with the `id_rsa_BAR` key.  What am I doing wrong?  Is this a bug?

I've read [this](https://gist.github.com/tobalsan/4008409), but that solution requires changing every remote repo url; there is no "default" key in that approach.  I would like to be able to leave the url unchanged for all repos that should use the "default" key (`id_rsa_BAR` in this example).

Comment: check out https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

Comment: Yeah, I've already seen a gist based on that one. I wanted something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what OS you're using, but I'm able to use multiple keys by using an SSH Key Agent.  I'm running Windows and using pageant.  I'd probably start with https://gist.github.com/tobalsan/4008409 .  I'm sure you can get an agent running for your OS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the gist, but it shows the approach I already know - i.e. defining separate ssh host aliases for *each* key. This requires using a custom url in all repos. I wanted to have a smarter solution, but I guess it's not possible.

Comment: I see now.  Have you tried putting the Host * at the top of your config?